# How to stop Notifications Banners and Alerts from grabbing keyboard focus

Tags: keyboard, notifications, sonoma

In the last day or so (maybe since I updated to macOS 14.2?) Notification Alerts or Banners grab the keyboard focus.

I.e. if I'm typing somewhere like iTerm or other places, when a Notification Banner or Alert happens, my keystrokes are start going to the Notification (get the system beep for each keystroke) and its no longer entering the keys on the application I was working on. The keystroke focus eventually goes back to the app I was working on, but it's very disrupting.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is this a bug in 14.2 or just a coincidence and the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Now that I've observed things more, it might not be Notifications per se though I do lose keyboard focus every time there is a notification. But I also lose keyboard focus at other times and I can't particularly tell why.